# Installing GuitarPro6 On Ubuntu 15.10 x86_64

Tags: software-installation, 15.10

#### What's Wrong

GuitarPro6 depends on firstly i386 libraries and then on some libraries that are not available in the repositories for 15.10.

15.10 is automatically enabled with MutliArch, so we don't need to change any base system settings

#### How are we going to fix?

We will

1. Unpack the DEB
2. Add the libraries it needs in the `/opt/GuitarPro6` folder (libssl0.9.8 and libportaudio0)
3. Edit the dependencies to remove libportaudio0, libssl0.9.8 and gksu
4. Repackage the DEB
5. Install the DEB

#### 1. Unpack the DEB

Download the DEB from Arobas and then lets unpack it

```
cd ~
dpkg -x gp6-full-linux-demo-r11686.deb gp
dpkg --control gp6-full-linux-demo-r11686.deb gp/DEBIAN/
```

#### 2. Add the libraries

Download the deb packages with `wget`

```
wget http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-4squeeze14_i386.deb
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/portaudio/libportaudio0_18.1-7.1_i386.deb
```

With archive manager, open each deb, drill down and find the following items (in `data.tar.gz` in the applicable package)

**in libssl0.9.8:

- libssl0.9.8.so
- libcrypto0.9.8.so

**in libportaudio0:

- libportaudio.so.0.0.18

Extract them to `~/gp/opt/GuitarPro6/`

#### 3. Edit the Dependencies

```
cd ~/gp/DEBIAN
```

edit the file called "control", remove gksu, libportaudio0 and libssl0.9.8

Also we need a symlink

```
ln -s ~/gp/opt/GuitarPro6/libportaudio.so.0.0.18 ~/gp/opt/GuitarPro6/libportaudio.so.0
```

#### 4. Repack the DEB

```
cd ~
dpkg -b gp gp.deb
```

#### 5. Install the DEB

```
dpkg -i --force-architecture gp.deb
apt-get install -f
apt-get install gksu
```

You can now startup and add the Licence code

Comment: Hello James, welcome to Ask Ubuntu ! Thanks for those detailed instructions. Ask Ubuntu use a Question & Answer model, so please, separate your question (How to install Guitar Pro 6?) of the answer. Use the answers fields below to post the solution of the problem and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/714528/edit) your question to only keep the "question" part. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks a lot, 2 years later, this is still the only way I found to install it on my new laptop with Ubuntu 17.10... and as GP7 has no support for linux, this post is infact the final install guide of GP on linux :)

Comment: Fails for me on the second wget (Ubuntu 20.04):-
`wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/portaudio/libportaudio0_18.1-7.1_i386.deb
--2020-09-01 16:24:18-- http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/portaudio/libportaudio0_18.1-7.1_i386.deb
Resolving ftp.de.debian.org (ftp.de.debian.org)... 141.76.2.4
Connecting to ftp.de.debian.org (ftp.de.debian.org)|141.76.2.4|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-09-01 16:24:18 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Comment: If you visit the link in a browser, that package is indeed unavailable. The [pool](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/portaudio19/) has libportaudio2 which I'm not sure would work.

Comment: This post is a combo answer/question in the same post, making this a "Needs details" "not a question" type situation.  Unless OP splits his answer out into a separate answer, this is not really a question.